# Jquery - How to insert content to the next empty DIV

Tags: jquery

I have a soccer field, and I want to add players on the field...

This already works fine (with drag and drop) and also with onClick() events.

But when i (via onClick() action() already added one player at a Defense Position, I want Jquery to add the next player next to the 1st Player...

Thats also works..

I implemented it with

```
 function addDefenderByClickEvent(playerName) {
     $('.defender').on('click', function () {   

      if( $('#defendLine').find('img').length ){

        $('#defendLine div:first').next().html("SOME HTML CODE".concat(playerName));  

        }else{                          
          $('#defendLine div:first').html("SOME HTML CODE".concat(playerName));                              
      }});
```

but this code added the first player and after that it just added the 2nd and 3rd Player always on the second PLace, becasue i used

```
#defendLine div:first').**next()**.html(SOME HTML CODE)
```

but it has to be more dynamicly (then just .next() ), i also tried to check if a position is empty, but when i have 2 or 3 free positions, jquery added the values to all empty positions, whats is not the best solution also.

Could you give me any hints maybe?

here is also my fiddle for now:
https://jsfiddle.net/54vgb8bx/65/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/54vgb8bx/70/

Above link is the updated and working version of your code`enter code here`

Comment: wowowowo but what are the differences to my code? :(

i am so happy man! THANK UUUUUU

Comment: Two differences. One of them is $('#defendLine div p').first().parent().html("SOME HTML CODE".concat(playerName));       and other is $(document).off('click', '.defender').on('click','.defender', function () {

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
$('#defendLine div:first').next().html("SOME HTML CODE".concat(playerName));
```

with

```
$('#defendLine div:empty').first().html("SOME HTML CODE".concat(playerName));
```

Assumptions:

```
<div id='defendLine'>
    <div></div> <!-- empty field -->
    <div><img..../></div> <!-- non empty field -->
</div>
```

Above replacement code will find the first empty div and inserts player into it, Hope this will help you

Comment: also thanks for your help man :)

BUT, my div is not empty --> in my div is a <p> Element and I also tried this here:

$('#defendLine div:has(p)').next().html(SOME HTML CODE))

also doesnt help :D but its close to the solution i am looking for...

do you have maybe another idea? maybe with jquery's .closest()

but it also not helped me out :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#defendLine div p').first().parent().html("SOME HTML CODE".concat(playerName));
```

if the empty field have `<p>` tag then, the above code may help it.

it searches for the div with p and selects the first div. Its like taking the div with p tag as empty field

Comment: look better now, but still not working correctly...

Please have a look here https://jsfiddle.net/54vgb8bx/67/ -------> Please klick on the name JEROME, then HOLGER, and then MATS.

then u will see, that after the 3rd player will be added to place of the 2nd player...

Comment: I edited the code please look at it. its .first().parent()

Comment: please look at my new answer, m sure this will help you... :)

Comment: could you maybe give ma a last hint, why my playerName is still there, after i put a player (by DRAG n DROP) into my field, and remove him right after that? se my updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/54vgb8bx/83/

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$('.defender').on('click', function () {
```

with

```
$(document).off('click', '.defender').on('click','.defender', function () {
```

Because each time when you click the player its adding the listener. The above code will remove the previous listener.